# Proper way to dynamically import a module with relative imports?

Tags: python, dynamic, import

I need to dynamically import modules into my project from another package.

The structure is like:

```
project_folder/
    project/
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
    plugins/
        __init__.py
        plugin1/
            __init__.py
            ...
        plugin2/
            __init__.py
            ...
```

I made this function to load a module:

```
import os

from importlib.util import spec_from_file_location, module_from_spec


def load_module(path, name=""):
    """ loads a module by path """
    try:
        name = name if name != "" else path.split(os.sep)[-1]  # take the module name by default
        spec = spec_from_file_location(name, os.path.join(path, "__init__.py"))
        plugin_module = module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(plugin_module)
        return plugin_module
    except Exception as e:
        print("failed to load module", path, "-->", e)
```

It works, unless the module uses relative imports:

> failed to load module /path/to/plugins/plugin1 --> Parent module 'plugin1' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The solution is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395128/1088938): you need to also add the imported module to `sys.modules` so that the relative import works.  I.e. include `sys.modules[spec.name] = plugin_module` just before you call `spec.loader.exec_module(plugin_module)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I managed to solve my own issue after a LOT of googling. Turns out I needed to import using relative paths:

```
>>> from importlib import import_module
>>> config = import_module("plugins.config")
>>> config
<module 'plugins.config' from '/path/to/plugins/config/__init__.py'>
>>>
```

Comment: How to do `from plugins.config import *`, using **import_module** or **__import__** ?

Comment: Been two years since i used importing in python, this saved me a bit of time messing about.. (yes i had absolute paths... grrr) .. cheers + 1

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem not long ago. I added the path of the project folder to the sys.path using the module's absolute path like this:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+'/..')
```

This adds the project_folder to the sys.path thus allowing the import statement to find the plugin modules.

Comment: Sadly this won't work for me. I added it to the beginning of my `project/__main__.py` file before I call `load_module`. Is that the correct place to put it?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this uses Python3. You could try to add an __init__.py to your project folder too.

Comment: Sorry, markdown screwed up my comment.
It should be another `__init__.py` file in the project_folder.