# How to access the current executing module's attributes from other modules?

Tags: python, module

I have several 'app'-modules (which are being started by a main-application)
and a utility module with some functionality:

```
my_utility/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __main__.py
apps/
    ├── app1/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __main__.py
    ├── app2/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __main__.py
    ...
main_app.py
```

The apps are being started like this (by the main application):

```
python3 -m <app-name>
```

I need to provide some meta information (tied to the module) about each app which is readable by the `main_app` and the apps themselves:

**apps/app1/__init__.py**:

```
meta_info = {'min_platform_version': '1.0',
             'logger_name': 'mm1'}
```

... and use it like this:

**apps/app1/__main__.py**:

```
from my_utility import handle_meta_info
# does something with meta_info (checking, etc.)
handle_meta_info()
```

**main_app.py**:

```
mod = importlib.import_module('app1')
meta_inf = getattr(mod, 'meta_info')
do_something(meta_inf)
```

### The Problem

I don't know how to access `meta_info` from within the apps. I know I *can* 
`import` the module itself and access `meta_info`:

**apps/app1/__main__.py**:

```
import app1
do_something(app1.meta_info)
```

But this is only possible if I know the name of the module. From inside another module - e.g. `my_utility` I don't know how to access the module which has been started in the first place (or it's name).

**my_utility/__main__.py**:

```
def handle_meta_info():
    import MAIN_MODULE        <-- don't know, what to import here
    do_something(MAIN_MODULE.meta_info)
```

### In other words

I don't know how to access `meta_info` from within an app's process (being started via `python3 -m <name>` *but from another module which does not know the name of the 'root' module which has been started*

### Approaches

- Always provide the module name when calling meta-info-functions (bad, because it's verbose and redundant)

  ```
  from my_utility import handle_meta_info
  handle_meta_info('app1')
  ```
- add `meta_info` to `__builtins__` (generally bad to pollute global space)
- Parse the command line (ugly)
- Analyze the call stack on `import my_utility` (dangerous, ugly)

### The solution I'd like to see

It would be nice to be able to either access the "main" modules global space OR know it's name (to import)

**my_utility/__main__.py**:

```
def handle_meta_info():
    do_something(__main_module__.meta_info)
```

OR

```
def handle_meta_info():
    if process_has_been_started_as_module():
        mod = importlib.import_module(name_of_main_module())
        meta_inf = getattr(mod, 'meta_info')
        do_something(meta_inf)
```

Any ideas?

**My current (bloody) solution:**

Inside `my_utility` I use `psutil` to get the command line the module has been started with (why not `sys.argv`? [Because](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634743/sys-argv-broken-if-module-started-via-m-name)). There I extract the module name. This way I attach the desired meta information to `my_utility` (so I have to load it only once).

**my_utility/__init__.py**:

```
def __get_executed_modules_meta_info__() -> dict:
    def get_executed_module_name()
        from psutil import Process
        from os import getpid
        _cmdline = Process(getpid()).cmdline
        try:
            # normal case: app has been started via 'python3 -m <app>'
            return _cmdline[_cmdline.index('-m') + 1]
        except ValueError:
            return None
    from importlib import import_module
    try:
        _main_module = import_module(get_module_name())
        return import_module(get_executed_module_name()).meta_info
    except AttributeError:
        return {}

__executed_modules_meta_info__ = __get_executed_modules_meta_info__()
```

Comment: So `main_app.py` is using e.g. `subprocess` to run these other modules "from the command line"? Why? And presumably it must know their names to do so - are you really asking *"how can you import a module by name"*? In which case see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/37808866/3001761

Comment: I'm not asking how to import a module by name (I'm using `import_module` in my examples already) - `main_app.py` imports the modules just to access their `meta_info` attribute. What I don't know is how to access `meta_info` from within the app's process *but from another module which does not know the name of the 'root' module which has been started*

Comment: So you want to access the `meta_info` from `app1/__init__.py` in `app1/__main__.py`? What's the *"main module"*? What *"other module"*? Better yet, could you give some more context about what you're really trying to achieve?

Comment: very close :). I  want to access `meta_info` from `app1/__init__.py` but not *directly* from `app1/__main__.py` but from a function called inside `app1/__main__.py` which itself is located inside another module (`my_utility` in my example)

Comment: Why not just make the `meta_info` an argument to that function, then?

Comment: because actually there are lots of functions/classes which want to access the "meta info about the module being executed" and I would have to provide it all the time.

Comment: To what end? Again, could you give some more context? And if you have to pass it to several different things, so what?

Comment: The `my_utility` module is just an example. Actually I have a bunch of modules with lot's of classes which all have to access the meta info of the currently executed module. Theoretically I can implement dependency injection for all classes but that would not be very readable or reusable.