# sys.argv broken if module started via '-m <name>'?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments

Trying to provide a dirty workaround for my problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606765/how-to-access-the-current-executing-modules-attributes-from-other-modules), I want to retrieve the name of the currently executed module by reading the command line.

But it looks like a higher power tries to prevent me from achieving my goal..

When I start `my_module` via

```
python3 -m my_module
```

`sys.argv` happens to be `['-m']`

Is this correct? Shouldn't it be either `[]`, `['my_module']` or even `['-m', 'my_module']`?

What can I do here to get 'my_module'?

**Note**: I know, I can always access `__name__` or `__package__`, but I **need** to find the name of the module from within a module different from the executed module itself.

**How to reproduce:**

I have the following  directory structure:

```
my_module/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── __main__.py
```

With `__main__` being empty and `__init__.py` only containing

```
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 -m my_module       
['-m']
```

**Workaround**:

In case you need something similar, here is how I did it in the end:

```
def get_module_name() -> str:
    from psutil import Process
    from os import getpid
    _cmdline = Process(getpid()).cmdline
    try:
        return _cmdline[_cmdline.index('-m') + 1]
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Comment: Cannot duplicate. `sys.argv` only contains the script filename itself here. Besides, the main module is always `__main__`.

Comment: which version of Python do you use? Mine is 3.5.1

Comment: and on another system it's 3.5.2 with same results.

Comment: Version 3.4.3 here.

Comment: When I change to using a package I get `['-c']`. But putting the code in `__main__.py` instead reverts to normal behavior.